# Format a int variable into a mm:ss

Tags: delphi, time, string-formatting

Can anyone help me how to format an int variable in delphi into a minute:seconds??

sample: 
myVar := 19;

my label caption should display 00:19

any idea anyone? thanks

Comment: nothing supplied there really, all i need is the to format it with 'mm:ss' this format

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming the `myVar` contains number of seconds:

```
label1.Caption := Format('%.2d:%.2d', [myVar div 60, myVar mod 60]);
```

Comment: There was a missing comma between Format arguments in my example, fixed now. Oh, looks like SimaWB beat me to fix it, thanks.

Comment: thanks for this,,, you just missed the , so that is why it displays Array Required error occurs,, Thanks

Comment: This is a somewhat brute-force method, there are more elegant solutions (see the answers that use `FormatDateTime`).

Answer (score 21):

This will avoid any errors for seconds values that overflow into hours.

```
var
  secs: integer;
  str: string;
begin
  secs := 236;
  // SecsPerDay comes from the SysUtils unit.
  str := FormatDateTime('nn:ss', secs / SecsPerDay));

  // If you need hours, too, just add "hh:" to the formatting string
  secs := 32236;
  str := FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss', secs / SecsPerDay));
end;
```

Comment: +1 This solution is easy to understand and will work with any input value. It's also the most flexible one.

Comment: `secs / SecsPerDay` actually converts `secs` to TDateTime: `TDateTime` holds the number of days in its integer part and the number of milliseconds it its fractional part.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [FormatDateTime method](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.FormatDateTime) like this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const MyConst: Integer = 19;
begin
  Caption:=FormatDateTime('nn:ss', EncodeTime(0, MyConst div 60, MyConst mod 60, 0));
end;
```

Comment: if MyConst > 60 there will be an `EConvertError`. better use it like this: `Caption := FormatDateTime('nn:ss', IncSecond(0, myVar));` (include `DateUtil`)

Comment: EncodeTime is best used when you have more than one part of a time to encode. In this case it's easier to divide by `SecsPerDay`

Answer (score 2):

Expanding onto Brad's answer, I've wrapped this into a function which detects if the time is over an hour, and automatically shows hours if so. Otherwise, if it's less than an hour, it doesn't show the hours. It also has an optional parameter to define whether to show a leading zero on the hours and minutes, depending on your preference (i.e. `03:06:32` vs `3:6:32`). This makes it a little more human-readable.

```
function SecsToTimeStr(const Secs: Integer; const LeadingZero: Boolean = False): String;
begin
  if Secs >= SecsPerHour then begin
    if LeadingZero then
      Result := FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss', Secs / SecsPerDay)
    else
      Result := FormatDateTime('h:n:ss', Secs / SecsPerDay)
  end else begin
    if LeadingZero then
      Result := FormatDateTime('nn:ss', Secs / SecsPerDay)
    else
      Result := FormatDateTime('n:ss', Secs / SecsPerDay)
  end;
end;
```

However, there are many different possible preferences with displaying a time period, which is up to you to decide. I won't cover all those possible ways here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you only want minutes and seconds - a quick solution could be:

Format('%d:%d',[(myVar div 60), (myVar mod 60)]);

Same solution as already proposed ... :-)